# How did Sirius get those pictures onto his walls?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black

In Deathly Hallows, Harry visits Sirius's room and sees this:

> The teenage Sirius had plastered the walls with so many posters and pictures that little of the walls' silvery-gray silk was visible.  Harry could only assume that Sirius' parents had been unable to remove the Permanent Sticking Charm that kept them on the wall

I am assuming that Harry is right--there is a Permanent Sticking Charm on these pictures.

In OotP, Sirius says this in a conversation with Harry:

> "You ran away from home?"
>
> "When I was about sixteen," said Sirius.  "I'd had enough."

So Sirius ran away from home when he was sixteen...but before that, he was able to put a Permanent Sticking Charm on his pictures, which is pretty complicated magic and would definitely violate that law about underage magic.  Did this happen, or is something else going on?

Comment: He probably bought some permanent sticking glue or something from a shop in Hogsmeade or Diagon Alley.

Comment: the trace doesnt work (right)in a wizarding house, he was probably breaking the law.

Comment: @TylerH, assuming that it is a permanent sticking charm (psc)

Comment: @CHEESE It was implied that "permanent sticking glue" was just some kind of glue with a permanent sticking charm applied to it by the manufacturer, thus allowing people to benefit from the permanent sticking charm without having to perform it themselves.

Comment: You ever try Gorilla glue?  That stuff will survive an asteroid with a nuclear bomb attached to it.  Or some kind of industrial-grade epoxy.

Comment: @CHEESE Do I miss something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "So if you're underage and you do magic inside an adult witch or wizard's house, the Ministry won't know?"
>
> "They will certainly be unable to tell who performed the magic," said Dumbledore, smiling slightly at the look of great indignation on Harry's face. "They rely on witch and wizard parents to enforce their offspring's obedience while within their walls."

Hence we can clearly deduce that he might have used a Permanent sticking charm on the wall because he can do that without being caught. The ministry cannot detect the magic around an underage wizard in vicinity of wizard/witches only.

Or else as Tyler said, he might have bought Some permanent glue from  Hogsmeade or Diagon Alley.

Comment: _Sirius ran away from home when he was sixteen_. So, who might be the adult wizards who are living with him?  In order to confuse the Ministry, there need to be atleast 2 adult wizards in the house (logically) :)

Comment: @Dawny33 he lived in a house full of wizards/witches, I think that should have been more than enough?

Comment: I didn't know that. (I'm still in Book-3). So, just asked. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @Dawny33 you shouldn't linger here now... too many spoilers... complete the books and get back soon :)...

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add onto @prakhar londhe's answer.

As he stated, and [The Trace](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trace) (section two):

> "So if you're underage and you do magic inside an adult witch or wizard's house, the Ministry won't know?"
>
> "They will certainly be unable to tell who performed the magic," said Dumbledore, smiling slightly at the look of great indignation on Harry's face. "They rely on witch and wizard parents to enforce their offspring's obedience while within their walls."

**Sirius could not be penalized as Harry was, and could not be technically accused of underage Magic due to his parents' presence.**

Moreover, Sirius was an exceptionally bright wizard, and was capable of successfully becoming an Animagus (one of the most advanced pieces of Magic), whilst still participating in Hogwarts.

In relevance to the Permanent Sticking Charm, transforming into a different creature is by far more advanced than the Charm, and it seems that Sirius would be extremely capable of learning it.